# Spark JDBC MySQL Syntax Error with column names with spaces

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark

I'm querying a MySQL table using PySpark JDBC. The problem I'm facing is that said table has column names with spaces.

In MySQL Workbench I would do the query like this to get the data and that works fine.

```
select
    `some id`
from
    table
```

But when I do it via PySpark like this:

```
query = 'select `some id` from table'

df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc') \
        .options(
        driver = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
        , url = some_connection_url
        , dbtable = query 
        , user = user
        , password = password
    ).load()
```

I get the following error message:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o497.load.
: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select
    `some id`
from 
    some_table WHERE 1=0' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've tried quoting the column names with `[]` and `""` but I get the same error message.

I'm also using the latest MySQL jars: `mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar` and Spark 2.4.

Any insights are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose your query in **brackets `()`** then try to pass to `read.format("jdbc")`.

**Example:**

```
query = '(select `some id` from table)e'

df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc') \
        .options(
        driver = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
        , url = some_connection_url
        , dbtable = query 
        , user = user
        , password = password
    ).load()
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much, @Shu! Do you happen to know why should it be enclosed with brackets?

Comment: @JoseDanielChacónBogarín, spark jdbc accpets `dbtable` as **parameter** and when we pass query we need to enclose query in bracket so that spark treats enclosed query as a **`table`** and executes the query on db.

Comment: I understand, and does that happen with every engine, such as PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc.; or that's just for MySQL?

Comment: @JoseDanielChacónBogarín, Yes, It happens with every engine!

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for your help, Shu, I really appreciate it :)